# Difference between Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator') and AerSimulator()

Tags: qiskit, programming, simulation, ibm-quantum-devices

In Qiskit, there are several ways to choose simulator: one is

```
from qiskit import Aer
backend = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator')
result = backend.run(circ).result()
```

another one is

```
from qiskit.providers.aer import AerSimulator
backend = AerSimulator()
result=backend.run(circ).result()
```

,where `circ` is `QuantumCircuit(n)`. Do they always return the same result?

Answer (score 4):

They're functionally equivalent the first approach is primarily just a shortcut that involves less typing to create a simulator backend and also follows the standardized "provider" interface for backends (which honestly makes more sense for remote backends, like real devices or remote simulators). But, both approaches will initialize a new [`AerSimulator`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.aer.AerSimulator.html#qiskit.providers.aer.AerSimulator) backend object with the default settings and if you run the circuit you will get roughly the same result with either.